# Trying to pull Data From a http website

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

ok so for a few days i have been playing around with HTML Agility pack

now i can take nodes from different websites and such
but i am trying to make a program that reads from a website to check available time slot for a game.

this is the html code i found that corresponds with what i want to do:

```
<input class="checkbox" disabled="" id="time10_20" value="10:20" type="radio" name="time">
```

as you can see the website lists it as disabled if the time slot is taken
If the time slot is not taken it doesn't write the disabled code

```
<input class="checkbox" id="time13_00" value="13:00" type="radio" name="time">
```

so yeah i know i know i have a lot to learn but i learn by experiments

thanks for the help in advance

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: i am tring to return a value if 1 if the space is free
or 0 if its not

Comment: And what goes wrong? Where's your code where you've tried this? P.S. If the site in question provides an API you'd be far better to use that. Otherwise when the site decide to re-design and change their layout your code will just stop working.

Comment: as i said i cant seem to find the code that checks if the 'disabled' is there or not
also i dont really know how to read that string in C#

Comment: No-one can fix a mere description of your code.

Comment: im asking for the code that can check for that not fix my code

Comment: you don't need to ask us that: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=htmlagilitypack+check+if+attribute+exists&oq=htmlagilitypack+check+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.7128j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8